# In mail.from ("content"), does "content" matter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp, email-client, mailmessage

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Mail As New MailMessage
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")

    Mail.Subject = Request.Form("subject")
    Mail.To.Add(Request.Form("toMail")))
    Mail.From = New MailAddress("content") 'Request.Form("username"))
    Mail.Body = Request.Form("body")

    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Request.Form("username"), Request.Form("password"))
    smtp.Port = "587"
    smtp.Send(Mail)

End Sub
```

In above code, I tried deleting the entire line of mail.from, it give me error.

I then tried adding Mail.From = New MailAddress("content") for "content" can be any string, I can thus receive the email perfectly and have the sender as my username which is Request.Form("username") **BUT NOT** the "content".

With this result, *what is the purpose of having mail.from then?* I do not need it because the system can generate a random string to put it inside and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MailMessage.From documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from(v=vs.110).aspx):

*"The from address is not validated or tied to the currently logged on user."*

So you can bascially set it to whatever you want. But being a good programmer you should set it to something meaningful.

This is the friendly name that shows to the user. You may or may not see this depending on your email client. Usually this displays like so:

`TripAdvisor <MemberUpdate@e.tripadvisor.com>`

Comment: Then what is the purpose of having it?

Comment: This is the friendly name shown to the person who receives it to say who it is from.

Comment: No, it did not show the "content", instead it showed the actual email that sends the mail.